# What is the definition of "scope" when we are talking about function hoisting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am learning [JavaScript Function Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#function_hoisting), which says "the declaration of functions are moved to the top of their scope". Then I read the definition of "scope" from this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope), it says "A function serves as a closure in JavaScript, and thus creates a scope". So does it mean any functions declared inside a function are moved to the top of that function? I use the following example to test:

```
foo();

function foo() {
   console.log(too);
   console.log(zoo);
   {
      function too() {console.log("too");}
   }
   function zoo() {console.log("zoo");}
}
```

The out put is

```
undefined
ƒ zoo() {console.log("zoo");}
```

So obviously the declaration of `too` is not moved to the top of `foo`. It is actually moved to the top of the block statement inside `foo`. So what is the exact definition of "scope" when we are talking about function hoisting in JavaScript?

Comment: *"So does it mean any functions declared inside a function are moved to the top of that function?"* Yes — **unless** they're in blocks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why is that?

Comment: "*A function serves as a closure in JavaScript, and thus creates a scope*" - that's rubbish. That functions can close over variables has nothing to do with a scope being created for the body of the function.

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, MDN is mostly great with occasional truly awful clangers like that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Function declarations in blocks were unspecified until ES2015, but allowed as an extension to the spec. So JavaScript engines extended the spec...in different ways, and in ways that differed over time. ES2015 standardized what it could, defining the handling of function declarations in blocks where it could be defined in a way that matched the overlapping behaviors. The resulting rules are complex, Just Say No. ;-) If you have to create a function in a block, use a function expression assigned to a variable/constant.

Comment: You could try https://ui.dev/?code=foo%28%29%3B%0A%0Afunction%20foo%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20console.log%28too%29%3B%0A%20%20%20console.log%28zoo%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20too%28%29%20%7Bconsole.log%28%22too%22%29%3B%7D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20function%20zoo%28%29%20%7Bconsole.log%28%22zoo%22%29%3B%7D%0A%7D to understand the scopes, hoisting and closures in your code. But it seems to show hoisting even if functions are in blocks so it might not be accurate for this specific rule

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see, thanks for your answer. So if I understand correctly, can I say functions declared inside a block are moved to the top of that block?

Comment: @Bergi — MDN welcome corrections: https://github.com/mdn/content

Comment: @RichardHu - Yes, in broad terms. I go into details in Chapter 3 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. But I strongly recommend just not using function declarations in blocks at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot. I am actually developing a code analysis tool for JavaScript, I have to learn how to handle function declarations inside blocks, even though it is not encouraged...

Comment: @RichardHu - The gory details are [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation) and [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics), mostly.